# String out of range c++

Tags: c++

when I try to check if the `str[index]` equal to I got exception ***String out of range***

```
std::string Test::getTheText(std::string str) {
    int index = 7;
    string text;
    cout << str[index] << endl; // Work!!

    while (str[index] != '\"') // Exception,why?? also try while(str[index]!=34)
        text += str[index++];
    return text;
}
```

my string is: Text – `bla bla`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Why the below code works?*
>
> ```
> std::string str = "bla bla";
> int index = 7;
> cout << str[index] << endl; // Work!!
> ```

If the `index` is equal to the string's length (in your case **it is**, `7 == strlen("bla bla")`), the access operator returns a reference to a default value of `charT` in `std::basic_string<charT>` instantiation, for `char` it is `\0`).

[C++ string::operator[] reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)

> If pos is **not greater** than the string length, the function **never throws** exceptions (no-throw guarantee).

However, later on you try to access another element:

```
str[index++] // in second iteration, the first is ok though
```

And **only then** you fall into:

> [...], it causes *undefined behavior*.

C++ Standard reference:

> **§ 21.4.5 basic_string element access [string.access]**
>
> ```
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> reference operator[](size_type pos);
> ```
>
> 1. *Requires:* **`pos <= size()`**
> 2. *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.
> 3. *Throws:* **Nothing.**

That is, as long as `pos <= size()` condition is satisfied, the method never throws, otherwise the behavior is *Undefined*, that throwing an exception is one of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Array entries are usually 0 based counted, so it's crucial to define your search range between 0 and string::length - 1. In C++ sometimes it returns garbage when you access string[n] (n >= len), and writing to it usually causes segment fault, based on my tragic experiences.